# Can website cookies (ie. from Facebook) track me when I use the same browser to browse other websites?

Tags: browser, privacy

Recently, I've been doing research on Google on home improvement articles. I use the same browser -- Brave, which touts its privacy settings right from get-go -- occasionally to check Facebook. I did not type anything in the Facebook search bar and did not comment or like any posts during this period. A few days ago, I found Facebook recommending "A Bunch of Dads Home Improvement" group to me.

I thought, ok maybe that's a coincidence. Then a few days ago, I browsed Shipt.com for about 20 min. Today, I found Facebook recommending Shipt articles to me. This is really scary. Cross-site cookies are blocked in my Brave setting. Is there anything else one can do protect privacy?

[image]

Comment: Yes; Facebook can use its cookies to track you if the website has Facebook social integration. Google can also track you by the way.

Comment: Through browser fingerprinting, a user may be identified even without ordinary cookies. For example, the IP address, HTML5 is LocalStorage, canvas properties, etc. See https://pixelprivacy.com/resources/browser-fingerprinting/ if you're concerned about browsing privacy.

Comment: idk if Windows has an equivalent to Safari, but cross-site tracking prevention is built-in to macOS - https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9eVc.png . That plus any decent AdBlocker [Ad Guard or Ad Block] ought to keep most of this stuff away from your browser.

Answer (score 4):

Cookies are one mechanism by which websites can track your activity,
but this is only one of the methods that Facebook has to track your
activity on the internet. Facebook can track your activity even if
you have no Facebook account and have never even logged into Facebook.

Facebook is owner of several web products, such as Instagram and Whatsapp,
but not only. All of them feed your data into its centralized database.
It has also got agreements with many websites and companies
to furnish it with data about their customers, which includes login-name
and activity, IP address and more. With this data, Facebook can very
well identify you almost always and everywhere and build for you a very
detailed profile.

Every website that offers you to login via a Facebook account,
or that has the Facebook logo on its page, or shows a Facebook
advertisement will likely be tracking you and reporting your data
to Facebook.

You may stop some of the web activity being used to target you with ads
by visiting the
[YourAdChoices site](http://optout.aboutads.info/)
run by the Digital Advertising Alliance.
Facebook advertising targeting is on the list of entries, so tick the
Opt Out box for that. You'll need to do this separately for each
browser you use; for a clean sweep, you should opt out of all the
other platforms as well.

You can't really stop Facebook from collecting this information -
it's the deal you make when you sign up - but you can limit how it
affects the advertising you see by visiting the ad preferences page
of your account.
The Ad settings page has more options, such as whether Facebook can use
data from its marketing partners (there are an awful lot of them)
to put more relevant advertising in front of you.

Note that all this won't stop Facebook from compiling your personal
profile, only limit its usage of your data (if you believe Facebook).

Some references :

- [All the Ways Facebook Tracks You—and How to Limit It](https://www.wired.com/story/ways-facebook-tracks-you-limit-it/)
- [Facebook Is Tracking You! Here's How to Stop It](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/facebook-tracking-stop/)
- [How to Keep Facebook From Tracking You](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/keep-facebook-tracking-70810.html)

Please note that there is no sure way of avoiding *all* the tracking methods
used by Facebook and its partners. See also:

- [Unique Browser / User ID?](https://superuser.com/questions/1467052/unique-browser-user-id)

Answer (score 0):

Most ads on the web are through the google ad service. Facebook does not have these cookies and shipt.com does not have these cookies, rather the ad iFrame (that connects to google) has all these cookies.

The google ad page keeps all these cookies. It collects what website youre on (also tracks things like things youve been searching) and puts all this information together into something that it think might interest you.

Facebook cannot access any info from shipt.com. The cookies in the google ad frame are not accessible to the parent (the only one that has your information is google, which is still pretty scary)