# Search topic at home device is pushed as ad banner on my office device's Yahoo page -- am I being hacked?

Tags: google-chrome, router, security, cookies, google-search

What I searched at home appeared as ad banner on my office device on Yahoo page, this is too creepy

1.both browsers are not login nor sync
2.the office device is new and I set it up at home (that's the only time they were on the same network)
3. Not a coincidence, I tried that for 2 days with uncommon products

Is my office device or even home router already being hacked?  There is no way those 2 devices are sharing history or cookies.  When I bought the new laptop, the staff set up for me while I was away for an hour....

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Most commercial services have data-sharing agreements with many other
companies and websites.

It's enough to have signed-on to some website on both computers while using
the same account, for both your computers to become identified with you,
if this website has partnership with some commercial entity.

The computer or the browser you're using can be identified by various
means. For more information see
[Unique Browser / User ID?](https://superuser.com/a/1467062/8672)

Comment: Thanks so much, now I have a hint that could be Yahoo mail.